# Adding child elements to checkbox/radio form elements

Tags: 7, forms

How can I add child elements to a checkbox/radio element? I have the following code.

```
$form['search_product'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radio',
    '#title' => t('Product'),
);

$form['search_product']['search_attributes'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#options' => array(
        'name' => t('by Name'),
        'model' => t('by Model'),
        'catalog_no' => t('by Catalogue No.'),
        'manufacturer' => t('by Manufacturer'),
        'description' => t('by Description'),
    ),
);
```

"search_attributes" checkboxes don't show up on the form, and I have only one radio.

Comment: Do you want to show the 'search_attributes' checkboxes if 'search_product' is selected? Why you set it like a parent?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can make a radio button a "parent".

Here's an example of using radios, checkboxes, and fieldsets.

http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example!form_example_states.inc/function/form_example_states_form/7

You might take a look at http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#container

Try removing search_attributes from search_product

```
$form['search_attributes'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#options' => array(
        'name' => t('by Name'),
        'model' => t('by Model'),
        'catalog_no' => t('by Catalogue No.'),
        'manufacturer' => t('by Manufacturer'),
        'description' => t('by Description'),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. To get checkboxes to be rendered, i'd suggest you go about it like so:

```
$form['search_product']['search_attributes'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#options' => array(
        'name' => t('by Name'),
        'model' => t('by Model'),
        'catalog_no' => t('by Catalogue No.'),
        'manufacturer' => t('by Manufacturer'),
        'description' => t('by Description'),
    ),
);
$form['search_product']['search_attributes'] = form_process_checkboxes($form['search_product']['search_attributes']);
```